# Declaring variable with inside function to define its value

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain to me why this doesn't work?
At first, I thought it was because Javascript closures but I'm not so sure

```
let accounts = [];
accounts[0] = 30;
accounts[1] = 25;
accounts[2] = 45;

var totalBalance = accounts.forEach(function(obj){
    totalBalance += obj;
    console.log(totalBalance)
})

console.log(totalBalance);
```

The output of this last console.log is undefined

Comment: simple reason: `forEach` returns `undefined`. And that's the last thing written to `totalBalance`. Either loop and inside the loop write to `totalBalance` but don't assign the result of `forEach` to it or use a `reduce` which *does* return a value and assign that result to `totalBalance`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not assigning a function to totalBalance, you're assigning whatever forEach returns. Let's [check in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)?

```
Return value
undefined.
```

Therefore, it only makes sense that your variable is undefined.
Here, this works better:

```js
let accounts = [];
accounts[0] = 30;
accounts[1] = 25;
accounts[2] = 45;

var totalBalance = 0; 
accounts.forEach(function(obj){
    totalBalance += obj;
    console.log(totalBalance)
})

console.log(totalBalance);
```